# during pull changes from remote repo into live server the software become broken

Tags: git, server, pull

During pull changes from remote repo into live server using (git pull origin master) command the software become broken, for some seconds max one or two minutes, but the users sometimes catch this interval and complaint, any suggestion?

Comment: Please describe what you are using and what is breaking. What research have you done so far and what exactly do you want to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Since pull is a long operation

> for some seconds max one or two minutes

you shouldn't do it on a live server.
you can use several ways of HA (high availability.

here is one simple option:
you can have another copy to which you pull, and serve it instead while you update (pull for your live server), and then switch back.